# Visual Studio 2008 solution (SSRS reports) to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

Does anyone know if it's possible to convert a `Visual Studio 2008` solution file containing `SSRS` reports (*.sln*, with *.rptproj* and *.rdl* files) to `Visual Studio 2013`? We are running `SQL Server 2012`.

I have the `SQL Server Data Tools` installed with `Visual Studio 2013` (per the research I've tried to do on this already). The error I'm getting is:

> "This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio."

I'm just not sure how to make it compatible?

I also don't know if I can jump so many versions in `Visual Studio` (skipping 2010 and 2012), and if/how `Visual Studio 2013` works with `SQL 2012` re: `SSRS`.

I tried looking into the `SQL Business Development` download but the one for `Visual Studio 2013` was for **SQL 2014** and the one for **SQL 2012** was for `Visual Studio 2012` (or 2010. Either way it wasn't 2013).

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Server Data Tools are cumulative support for each version of SQL so the latest version supports SQL 2014 and previous versions, not just SQL 2014.

[SQL Server Data Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/03/25/sql-server-data-tools-for-sql-server-2014-is-available.aspx)

The SQL Server BI tools are also this way and will support down level SQL versions as is documented in this blog post [SQL BI Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2014/04/02/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-ssdt-bi.aspx)

By installing this the latest version it should properly support the conversion of your project type.

If you are still not sure, please read this Microsoft Connect article that describes your error message of the project is not compatible and see the workaround for similar information above [Project Not Compatible](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/767209/sql-server-report-project-unsupported-in-visual-studio-2012).

Comment: Per the first link, I did the following: "For Visual Studio 2013 download check the Visual Studio update channel (Tools –> Extensions and Updates –> Updates) for this update." However, I got the same result. I'm going to see if I can go to Visual Studio 2010 and then to 2013.

Comment: The following seemed to work. (The link off of the second link above.) I was under the impression it was going to install SQL Server 2014, but it did not (just the reporting services). Thank you! http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313